# Adaptive FitText: is there a better way to do it?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a piece of code that adapts [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/) to custom media queries. I wanted it to have different values for each predefined media query.

The code works, but it is by far ugly and by far not optimal.

http://jsfiddle.net/rKFYs/9/

I've tried recoding it but my js skills are not that good.

JS Gurus, please help!

Comment: This is usually done with CSS, BTW, not JS. Unless you want to support IE8 and below.

Comment: @Blender I think I'm not making myself clear http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: @Blender Say you want to use FitText, but with different values depending on the media query you are using. If you are on mobile I'll use certain scale, maximum and minimum size for fittext. If you use a desktop it would be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up writing my own plugin called [AdaptiveText.js](https://github.com/aficiomaquinas/AdaptiveText.js) check it out!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a remix of FitText a little while back that will do its best to scale your text to fit its container element (see http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/11/fit-text-to-element-inflatetext-js/).

Using this variation on the FitText concept, you would simply need to adjust the size of the container div in your media queries and let the plugin scale your text to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900533/have-font-size-change-according-to-size-of-div/20123694#20123694) that I just wrote in other question about a similar problem can help you