# Setting font-size so that letter height equals a certain value

Tags: css, font-size

I want to scale a letter to the exact height of another element with CSS. For example, I might want to have text that is exactly as high as some image:

[image]

#### How can I achieve this?

When I set font-size equal to the height of the image, the letters are smaller. I can try to adjust this manually, until it *looks* equal, but I'd like to calculate it.

---

My current solution is to set line height to the height of the image, and to calculate font-size from the font metrics:

```
.the_image {
    height: 28px;
    }

.the_M {
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: calc(28px * 2048 / 1490);
    }
```

In this case, the font metrics are 2048 UPM (units per em), and the letter "M" is 1490 units high. Dividing the em size (2048 units) by the letter height (1490) results in a factor that scales the "M" to the desired height (here: 28px).

In this case I know the font that I use, because I embed it with @font-face, and I know the metrics of the font because I looked at it in a font editor (I'm using Fontforge and Glyphs to create my fonts), but I'd still like **a solution that works for unknown fonts** from the user's computer.

Comment: I have just inspected part of the text of this question using chrome dev tools and it looks like text "How can I achieve that?" is `17px`, but the computed height for the div is `22px` and I don't think you have much control over it, unless you set the `line-height` to be `17px` as well

Comment: Why do you need to set the div height? Why can't you just set the font size and leave `div` to expand to the font height?

Comment: @Morpheus I adjusted my example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718840/make-text-height-100-of-div

Comment: Well, there is [`font-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust), which does exactly what you want, but 1) it works on lowercase letters rather than uppercase, and 2) browser support is abysmal. Oh well. Anyway, here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yvo5xhkq/).

Comment: This isn't just a matter of the font being used. It's also a matter of which character glyph is being used. You can't really match that with CSS.

Comment: Have you considered the use of [fontmetrics.js](http://pomax.github.io/fontmetrics.js/) or [font.js](https://github.com/Pomax/Font.js)?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set position and then inherit height
Something like:

```
    .the_M{
           position : relative;
           height : inherit;
     }
```