# Increase text size to fit table cell for only one column

Tags: html, css

I am developing an Angular web page that has a table. I did eberything in Angular side, Now I am struggling with CSS/HTML side. I have to display the data in one column as bigger text. That means the text should fit the entire height of the table row.

So I created a fiddle (no angular included, only html and css).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/SudhirSahoo/agxc18Ly][1]
```

I am using bootstrap and the screen size may differ. If I give fixed line-height in text3 css class, then it works in one screen, but in another bigger screen, it does n't look good.

In the fiddle I want to display the defects in "This Qtr" column as shown in below image.
[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible with only css, but with JS you can do it!
I found a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718840/make-text-height-100-of-div) about similar issue and changed it a bit to work on table cell.

So what is happening is that every resize or page load we get the height of it and set the font size to height * 2. `td:nth-child(2)` selects the second cell.

Second example is set to 100px height, first have have no height

```js
var $td = $('.t1 td:nth-child(2)');

$(window).resize(function () {
   var height = $td.height();
   $td.css({
      'font-size': (height * 2) + 'px',
      'line-height': height + 'px'
   })
}).trigger('resize');

var $tds = $('.t2 td:nth-child(2)');

$(window).resize(function () {
   var height = $tds.height();
   $tds.css({
      'font-size': (height * 1.5) + 'px',
      'line-height': height + 'px'
   })
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.t2 td{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="t1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>This Qtr</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <h4>second table</h4>
  
<table class="t2">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>This Qtr</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this what exactly I want, but I am new in Angular, so I find it is not straight forward to use JQuery with angular. Trying to find a way to do in Angular

Comment: Hello Sid, will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event The solution by @pepega is changing the style on resize of window. You can write the resize function in Angular to do this.

Comment: @Sid yeah that's true, but I hope this helped a little in how to think when solving your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @PEPEGA - I worke din JQuery earlier (about 3-4 years back) and used similar logic. Was wondering if anything ready-made available in HTML5/CSS3. but I will still upvote this one

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `line-height: 0` and `padding-top: 22px` from `.text-3`.

Here the working code: https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/mddBvYj

I hope this will help.

Thanks,

Neha

Comment: With your code, the font-size increases, but the height of row also increases, which I don't want

Comment: You don't need extra white-space within the top & bottom of the row?

Comment: I don't need white space above and below of the text inside that cell only

Answer (score -1):

I think the below changes in the CSS file can fix the problem.

```
.text3 {
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 0;
        padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```