# How to automatically resize text CSS?

Tags: css

I have a block with fixed height:

```css
div {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" height="200px">
  text...
</div>
```

How to resize text if it does not fit in div by height?

Comment: I think this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718840/make-text-height-100-of-div) might help you. Just a heads up, it makes use of scripts to attain the desired result though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the javaScript

```
<div id = "theId" class="card" height="200px">
    text...
</div>
<script>
    let theNewHeight = "16px"
    document.getElementById("theId").style.height = theNewHeight;
</script>
```

or set the value in css to % instead of px

```
div {
   font-size: 16%;
}
```

that 'll change it depending on the size of document, witch means 16% of the document.